# Как правильно использовать классы и обьекты JAVA

Tags: java, ооп, классы, объекты

Как Правильно использовать классы и обьекты в JAVA? 
Добавил:
Я сейчас в свободном плавании, решил изучить JAVA, знаю как создавать классы, обьекты, поля, конструкторы, инкапсуляцию, но не знаю как ее применить в написании программы) Я сейчас должен сделать Авторизацию храня данные в файле(txt)(FileReader/Writer) и хочу использовать классы и обьекты, вот только не понимаю как это все правильно сделать.
Вы уже простите дилетанта.

Comment: а по поводу того, «как и зачем использовать» структуры и переменные у вас вопросов нет?

Comment: Затем, чтобы программировать. А как можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит довольно по-хамски. "Как и зачем вы используете еду? С подробностями и примерами рецептов.  И быстро!" С подробностями и примерами -- это называется "книга". Их уже написано довольно много, есть по тысяче страниц, есть по две. Читайте. Персонально для вас здесь вряд ли кто-то напишет новую.

Comment: Вопрос был более понятен, если бы касался с++, тк там можно в процедурном стиле все делать. В джава же все - объекты. Без них нет джава. Вангую, это вопрос из какого-нибудь билета контрольной по программированию

Comment: Нет нет)) Я сейчас в свободном плавании, решил изучить JAVA, знаю как создавать классы, обьекты, поля, конструкторы, инкапсуляцию, но не знаю как ее применить в написании программы) Я сейчас должен сделать Авторизацию храня данные в файле(txt)(FileReader/Writer) и хочу использовать классы и обьекты, вот только не понимаю как это все сделать

Answer (score 3):

Рискну

Многие вещи на свете подобны друг другу. Схожи по своим характеристикам. Вычленять подобные вещи по группам можно бесконечно. Группы из чего-то подобного друг другу состоят. Их может быть мало, много, может не быть вовсе, а может быть бесконечное количество. Оперировать группами в некоторых случаях удобнее, чем тем из чего они состоят.

Многое на свете взаимодействует друг с другом. Программист перекладывает модель решаемой задачи, например, из реальной жизненной ситуации, на модель программы.

Классы для программирования можно сравнить с группами. Объекты можно сравнить с составляющими групп.

То как устроены классы и объекты и как этим оперировать можно рассказывать и рассказывать, особенно если слушателю интересно. Обычно те кому действительно интересно, например вы, проходят долгий путь по этому славному пути, пути программирования. Только так и приходит понимание.